# Python Sqlite : Database not writable, if stored in ProgramFiles

Tags: python, sqlite, rights, program-files

I am making a python application which read TXT files and import them in a sqlite file.db
I worked in a preprod environment in my %userdir% so the code is totally ok, but since i moved the .db in a ProgramFiles directory (win 10), it seems neither DB browser for Sqlite nor my script, can't write the file.
However, the read queries work.

I know the UAC and windows now protects directories out of appdata and userdir for some reasons, but i don't get it : when an (whatever) application, installed by setup, create a directory with a db in ProgramFiles, it works. Even if i retire my local admin right to my own windows user, the app maintains its right to write. And this, without creating an other user.

What should i do ? The application i write has to be installed on an unknown number of target machines, i just can't change (and break) ACLs on ProgramFiles directories. And there is no reason the db would be stored in a appdata user profile directory, because the program has to run from any window session, once installed.

What are the "normal" best practices to store the .db ?

Thanks to contributors.

Answer (score 0):

The standard location in windows for something like this is the ProgramData folder not ProgramFiles.  Will that work for you?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of that. I'm gonna try and tell you back, thank you.

Comment: This works, this was the correct answer !